# After if statemant foreach key missing

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, switch-statement

I have a strange behaviour in my code.

```
function what_ever($array){
  foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if($value === TRUE){
      switch($key){
        case 'xx':
          ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After the if the $key is empty/gone what ever.
Code like this works fine:

```
function what_ever($array){
  foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if($value == TRUE){
      switch($key){
        case 'xx':
          ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second snippet is using only == instead of ===. But shouldn't it work anyway? If not why not?

Comment: probably $value is evaluated to true but it's not "true" as value (i mean that it's not a boolean, but is something evaluated as true if converted to a boolean) and so the problem is not the "$key" that is disappearing, but the fact that you are not going inside the if

Comment: Take a read here on comparions operators https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Berto99 You are absolutly right. It's to late in germany, need to finish for today. Thanks for hitting my face into that.

Comment: well, i'm from italy and so i can understand you ahah

Comment: nevermind, it happens to all of us :)